# Vertically align text using no divs

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time, and it seems to be very close to working, but it just won't align vertically. I've tried the most of the solutions out, while going back to the same table-cell answer. It doesn't work here though, the text gets aligned right at the top. Does anyone know why this doesn't work, as well as a fix for it?

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/JyvbJ/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">Open Up</a>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    -moz-border-radius: 120px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 120px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 120px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}​
```

**How it looks like (LEFT: NORMAL | RIGHT: HOVER):**

[image: Pic:]

P.S I can't have any divs because I want the entire circle to be clickable as the link. Thanks

Comment: This question might be clearer if you had a picture of what you want it to look like as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute` doesn't mix with `display: table-cell`. Remove that and the `display: block` in the `:hover` rules and it works. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JyvbJ/17/)

Comment: Ugh, thought this would be the answer, but I need it to show up on top of an image. So that's why I'm using position absolute, unless you can think up of something else that would take it out of the flow.

Comment: Wrap the entire thing in a div and absolutely position that wrapper. Don't think there's any other solution other than the `line-height` technique mentioned upstream by Aaron.

Comment: Line-height is not really necessary in this case (setting <a> position to table-cell). And, as you said, removing the display: block; solves the problem, and it works with multi-line and the text is above the gray bg and/or img.

Comment: @steveax that's awesome. But for my purpose I can't have a span in the middle. I can have one that wraps outside of it. Does that help?

Comment: @EGHDK that's exactly what I was suggesting: wrap the `<a>` element in a div and position the wrapper div rather than the `<a>` element.

Comment: Gotcha, seems like that's my last resort. But I still can't get it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/A5seC/1/

Comment: @EGHDK you used `display: table` rather than `display: table-cell` in your latest fiddle. [Updated (fixed) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5seC/2/)

Comment: Thanks for sticking through this to help me out. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `line-height` of your element to equal the `height`, i.e: `line-height: 240px;`

**EDIT:** for multi-line support, put a `span` inside the anchor tag, style it with `display table-cell; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;`, and style the containing anchor tag with `display: table;`, as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A5seC/).

Comment: Yeah, but when sentence is long is doesn't wrap around. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this article. I think it will be helpful if you're willing to change your code a bit. Without it I think it won't be possible, unless you use something else like jquery.
[Here's the link to the article](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)
Hope it helps!

Edit: Just to help you a little bit more: change a { position: absolute; } to a { display:table-cell; } and delete the line a:hover { display: block }

Comment: Yeah, a couple of people have come up with that answer, but it needs absolute positioning.